# jquery triggering a function by id only affects the 1st element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to trigger a popup notification when an anchor is clicked. For that Im using a jquery and triggering the button by its ID. I have a few buttons with the same id that i want to trigger the same notification when the user clicks. But now the notification only appears in the top most element with the id.

```
$("#applebutton").click(function(e){
    $(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $.bootstrapGrowl("Notification", { 
                type: 'info',
                align:'center',
                width:'auto',
            });
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

Comment: `I have a few buttons with the same id` this is invalid. Use classes to group elements. You can also remove the `$(function() {})` from the click handler.

Comment: if it is not possible to give it to a class lets say i have two anchors with same class, and i want only 1 of them to pop up the notification and when i scroll down i have another 2 buttons with the same class and only 1 should pop up the notification. Then what is the most efficient solution

Comment: Then only apply the class to the element that you want to trigger the event.

Comment: If you show your HTML as well, we can show a more precise solution.

Answer (score 2):

IDs must be unique on each document context to be valid HTML.

Browsers have a fast lookup table that contains only one element per key value, so any search by ID will only return the first match.

Use classes instead.

Please note your DOM ready handler is pointless inside the click handler and should be removed too.

e.g.

```
$(".applebutton").click(function(e){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.bootstrapGrowl("Notification", { 
            type: 'info',
            align:'center',
            width:'auto',
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

or if they are added dynamically, use a delegated event handler attached to a non-changing ancestor:

```
$(document).on("click", ".applebutton", function(e){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.bootstrapGrowl("Notification", { 
            type: 'info',
            align:'center',
            width:'auto',
        });
    }, 100);
});
```

`document` is the best default for delegated events *if there is not another closer ancestor element*.

Note: Avoid using `"body"` as it has a bug (if the computed body height is zero, e.g. if the content is positioned absolutely, mouse events will not bubble to it on some browsers).

Answer (score 0):

id should be unique, that is why this happens. If you want to have multiple elements with the same identifier, use class instead of id, and refer it using

```
$(".applebutton")
```

instead of

```
$("#applebutton")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use same id again, Use Classes that can be used anywhere. it will solve your problem. 
For example I've HTML code like this

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#popup" class="clickme" >CLick 1</a></li>
 <li><a href="#popup" class="clickme" >CLick 2</a></li>
 <li><a href="#popup" class="clickme" >CLick 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can simply use Classes to perform any action via `jQuery` Like this

```
$(function(){
  $(".clickme").click(function(){
     // anything you wanted to do.. for all the links with only one class

   });
});
```